# Does using Polyfills/ transpiler makes our site slower?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, transpiler

I know for polyfills we need to add one additional if condition and then implement/add missing functionality.
And transpiler rewrite's modern code using older syntax constructs, so that the result would be the same.

So this must take some time, right? So in what ways it affects our site loading and response time?

Comment: The only one who can answer that for your particular site is you. Measure how it's slower with and without polyfills.

Comment: Transpilers do not affect your site loading and response time. The code is transpiled once and then it's there to be used. Using polyfills shouldn't have a big impact on your site's performance too, since transpilers usually generate quite performant code. It is definitely faster than if you tried to implement the same features yourself in an older version of JS

Comment: Transpiling typically happens during development and not at runtime. And also loading polyfills happens only once at startup. It may have a (typically very small) impact, but to be honest: whats the alternative? If you want to support older browsers, you'll have to do add the respective code. And typically the code from polyfills and transpilers is way better than everything an average coder writes ... And also from the point of maintenance and security it's best to trust some code that is used in a huge number of projects already than inventing everythiing on your own again.